# How do I limit an ajax call to the scope with the provided parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scope

I am trying to 'fill' a select in a form, based on a stored (array) value: `city_selector_vars`. This stored value shows the correct values (see code below).

I loop through this array and try to get the the cities (get_states) for the defined stateCode. I pass stateCode as a value into the function.

If I log `state_data.country_code` before `$.post` I get the expected return. If I log `state_data.country_code` inside `$.post` it's not always the same as the passed country_code. I think it has something to do with scope but my knowledge is not good enough to figure it out.

```js
/**
 * city_selector_vars
 * [
 *      'countryCode' => 'NL',
 *      'stateCode' => 'NL-FL',
 *      'cityName' => 'A name'
 * ]
 * [
 *      'countryCode' => 'BE',
 *      'stateCode' => 'BE-BR',
 *      'cityName' => 'Another name'
 * ]
 */
if ( true === Array.isArray(city_selector_vars) ) {
    for (i = 0; i < city_selector_vars.length; i++ ) {
        get_states(city_selector_vars[i].countryCode, (response)=> {
            // console.log(response);
        });
    }
}

function get_states(countryCode, callback) {
    const state_data = {
        action: 'get_states_call',
        country_code: countryCode
    };
    // console.log(state_data.country_code) shows correct country code
    $.post(ajaxurl, state_data, (response)=> {
        // here the wrong response first shows
        // state_data.country_code is not always the same as state_data.country_code
        callback(response);
    });
}
```

```php
function get_states_call( $country_code = false ) {
    // $country_code = always false, even though it is passed
    if ( false == $country_code ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'country_code' ] ) ) {
            // here it sometimes picks up the incorrect value
            $country_code = $_POST[ 'country_code' ];
        }
    }
    // code removed, since depends on code above
    $items = [];
    echo json_encode( $items );
    die();
}
```

Because it only sometimes picks up the wrong value, I think it has to do with scope, but I don't know enough to pinpoint it.

Comment: That's because AJAX is asynchronous. You don't know the order in which callbacks will be executed.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer the question :) You're merely stating a fact.

Comment: Yes, i've tried his solution but couldn't get it to work, probably because I didn't provide some more info about what's 'inside' get_states.

Comment: I added that as a parameter before already in get_states but that didn't seem to do the trick as far as I could tell.

Comment: If it's any info, the complete code can be found in this [file](https://github.com/Beee4life/acf-city-selector/blob/feature/repeater/assets/js/city-selector.js#L81).

Comment: @mateleco I just updated the adapted code, with some pointers by muka.gergely. With async/await I only got 1 result every time. When I remove it (but keep the rest of his code), I get the expected result. The console.log in the updated code (which can be found [here](https://github.com/Beee4life/acf-city-selector/blob/feature/promise/assets/js/city-selector.js#L97) gives me the expected result, but to use it I need to resolve the promise value and that's where it now messes the order up again.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that you are implementing a function to query **Wordpress** data.

I don't think your problem is one of variable scope - it's rather a problem of **async functions**. You send out one **AJAX** request per country - every request travels to the server "individually", get processed by the server, and the response comes back. **Nothing ensures** that the response arrives in the same order as the requests were sent out.

Consider this:

```js
const arr = []

function getSingleItem(id) {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.id)
    })
}

function getAllItems() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    getSingleItem(i)
  }
}

getAllItems()
```

You can see in the console, that the responses do not arrive in the order the requests were sent (`json.id` is actually a running number from 1 to `i` - they should be in order).

You have to take care of ordering yourself:

```js
const arr = []

function getSingleItem(id) {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return json.id
    })
}

async function getAllItems() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    const r = await getSingleItem(i)
    arr.push(r)
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

getAllItems()
```

By setting up an `async await` in the functions I can be sure, that the responses show up in the order the requests were sent out. (`await` does not "let" the `for()` loop to go further until the **awaited** response does not arrive - kinda' like synchronous code.)

In this case I use that the `fetch()` function returns a `Promise` object - an object that can be **await**ed in my other function.

### YOUR CODE

Your Javascript code can be modified:

```js
/**
 * city_selector_vars
 * [
 *      'countryCode' => 'NL',
 *      'stateCode' => 'NL-FL',
 *      'cityName' => 'A name'
 * ]
 * [
 *      'countryCode' => 'BE',
 *      'stateCode' => 'BE-BR',
 *      'cityName' => 'Another name'
 * ]
 */
async function get_all_state(city_selector_vars) {
  if (true === Array.isArray(city_selector_vars)) {
    // preparing the response array
    const response_states = []
    for (i = 0; i < city_selector_vars.length; i++) {
      // try - catch to handle errors
      try {
        // await the response
        const d = await get_states(city_selector_vars[i].countryCode);
        // add response to the response array
        response_states.push(d)
      } catch (err) {
        // handle error
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    // return the array - in order!
    return response_states
  }
}

function get_states(countryCode, callback) {
  const state_data = {
    action: 'get_states_call',
    country_code: countryCode
  };
  // console.log(state_data.country_code) shows correct country code

  // returning a Promise object, so await works in the other function
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.post(ajaxurl, state_data, (response) => {
      // here the wrong response first shows
      // state_data.country_code is not always the same as state_data.country_code
      // resolving the Promise when the response arrives
      resolve(response)
    });
  })


}
```

In your modified code a `Promise` had to be explicitly created (remember - `fetch()` returns a `Promise`?), so it can be handled by **async-await**.

I think the snippet should work as it is, but if not, then only a small debugging is needed :)

## WORDPRESS NOTE

If you send **JSON** with Wordpress, it's advised to use the `wp_send_json()` function.

More: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. While looking at your suggestion (and testing it) I felt some info (from my side was missing). Explained below.

> From your code it seems that you are implementing a function to query Wordpress data.
You are correct, you can find the plugin repo [here](https://github.com/Beee4life/acf-city-selector).
More specifically, the JS file is [here](https://github.com/Beee4life/acf-city-selector/blob/feature/repeater/assets/js/city-selector.js#L81). 1/2

Comment: I removed some code for the example but maybe a bit too much. If you click the second link it will take you to the function that is ‘causing’ the issue.

Your code worked partially, with some edits, but it only works for 1 instance, which I what I think was missing, info wise…
I need to call get_states and add the results for each instance in city_selector_vars, so within the loop (imo), because it’s part of an [ACF repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/).

Reg. wp_send_json; will look into it. 2/2

Comment: I was just testing your solution again, but I end up with an array containing 2x the same array, not 2 different sets. I get 2x the states for country NL instead of NL + BE.

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect... I get 1x NL... but not BE.

Comment: I have done some tweaking and I seem to be getting closer. See updated code [here](https://github.com/Beee4life/acf-city-selector/blob/feature/promise/assets/js/city-selector.js#L97). The console.log gives me the result I expect, every single time. The promise.resolve however messes the order up again :)

Comment: If you leave out the `await` in the **try-catch** block, then you don't really need the **try-catch** here. Sorry to say, but your code looks very complicated - try to simplify it (e.g. by extracting code to functions, thus breaking it down to smaller elements). Or you could try to get the data you want through the WP REST API (ACF fields can be added to the REST responses). But if `Promise.all()` works for you best - then go that way :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... I agree it is not the easiest/DRY... I will clean that up later, if everything works. Optimising is a later step. For now getting it to work is the main priority. And after 'applying the promise everywhere' everything seems to works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

As to the `admin_post_edit_load_states` function, I think [Promise.all](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-all) is the correct approach:

```
function admin_post_edit_load_states() {
    if (true === Array.isArray(city_selector_vars)) {
        // preparing the response array
        const response_states = []
        for (i = 0; i < city_selector_vars.length; i++) {
            // try - catch to handle errors
            try {
                // await the response
                const d = get_states(city_selector_vars[i].countryCode);
                // add response to the response array
                response_states.push(d)
            } catch (err) {
                // handle error
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        console.log(response_states);

        Promise.all(response_states).then(function(jsonResults) {
            var instance_count = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < jsonResults.length; i++) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(jsonResults[i]);
                var len = obj.length;
                var $stateValues = '';
                var select_state = $('select[name*="row-' + instance_count + '"][name*="stateCode"]');
                var stored_state = city_selector_vars[instance_count].stateCode;
                select_state.fadeIn();
                for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    $selected = '';
                    var state = obj[j];
                    var current_state = state.country_code + '-' + state.state_code;
                    if (current_state === stored_state) {
                        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                    }
                    var selected = $selected;
                    $stateValues += '<option value="' + state.country_code + '-' + state.state_code + '"' + selected + '>' + state.state_name + '</option>';
                }
                select_state.append($stateValues);
                instance_count++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This should keep the original order while being asynchronous. 
Notice what we are doing here:

First we fill the array `response_states` with promises (each call to get_states returns a promise). Then, `Promise.all(response_states)` creates a new promise that will be resolved when all the promises in the response_states array are resolved. Finally, the parameter jsonResults is an array containing the corresponding value for each resolved promise in the array `response_states`.

Let's see if it works.

Comment: Hey @mateleco, thanks for your reply. I used your code as is and the first few 3 tests all filled the select with the expected values so that looks very promising (no pun intended). I will apply your code to the 'cities select' as well. Will do some more testing and will let you know the results.